# How do I query a Key-Value object in Java

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list

If I have an array of strings, how do I query all VALUES in a key-value object with my listOfStrings, and return the related KEYS??

```
"listOfStrings": ["4444", "5555"]

"secretCodes": [
{
"secret": "John",
"value": "4444"
},
{
"secret": "Paul",
"value": "0001"
},
{
"secret": "George",
"value": "0002"
},
{
"secret": "Ringo",
"value": "5555"
},
{
"secret": "Pete",
"value": "0008"
}
]
```

Comment: Why is `secretCodes` an array instead of an object that maps from the values to the secrets?

Comment: Like `{"4444": "John", "0001": "Paul", ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the secret names that correspond to the values in the codes array you could do this:

```js
let secretCodes = [
  { secret: "John", value: "4444" },
  { secret: "Paul", value: "0001" },
  { secret: "George", value: "0002" },
  { secret: "Ringo", value: "5555" },
  { secret: "Pete", value: "0008" },
];

function getSecretName(codes) {
  let matchingValues = secretCodes.filter(obj => codes.includes(obj.value));
  return matchingValues.map(value => value.secret);
}

console.log(getSecretName(["4444", "5555"]));

// returns ["John", "Ringo"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your items and store them in a variable.

```
const secretObjects = [];

secretCodes.forEach(obj => {
  if (Codes.includes(obj.value)) {
    secretObjects.push(obj)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

After turning `secretCodes` and `codes` into variables, this will work:

```
secretCodes.forEach(x =>{
        codes.forEach(y =>{
            if (x['value'] === y){
                console.log(x['secret'])
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way to manage data like this is use the Array prototype functions.

- `filter` is best when you want an array containing a subset of the data
- `map` is best when you want to transform each element into a new
  element.
- `some` is best used when you want to know if any element in the array matches what you are looking for

```js
Codes = ["4444", "5555"]

secretCodes = [
{"secret": "John", "value": "4444"},
{"secret": "Paul", "value": "0001"},
{"secret": "George", "value": "0002"},
{"secret": "Ringo", "value": "5555"},
{"secret": "Pete", "value": "0008"}
]

const filteredCodes = secretCodes.filter(code => Codes.some( el => el === code.value))
console.log(filteredCodes)

const secretNames = filteredCodes.map(code => code.secret)
console.log(secretNames)
```